# Ajax function is not returning any output

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am using this ajax function to get options for two dropdown via ajax but it is not returning any output.
Hi this is my ajax function :

```
 <script>
$('#department').on('change',function(){
    var department = $(this).val();
    var course = $('#course').val();
    if(department){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data:{department: department, course: course },
            success: function(data){
                $('#head_name').html(data.head_name);
                $('#email').html(data.email);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#head_name').html('<option value="">Select Department first</option>'); 
        $('#email').html('<option value="">Select Department first</option>'); 
    }
});
</script>
```

And this is my query code:

```
if(isset($_POST["department"]) && isset($_POST["course"])){
    //Get all courses data

    $query = $db->query("SELECT head_name, email FROM head WHERE course = '".$_POST['course']."' AND department = '".$_POST['department']."' ");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display result list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

            $temp = array('head_name' => '<option value="'.$row['head_name'].'">'.$row['head_name'].'</option>', 'email' => '<option value="'.$row['email'].'">'.$row['email'].'</option>' );
            echo json_encode($temp);
        }
    }else{
        $temp = array('head_name' => '<option value="">Not avaialble </option>', 'email' => '<option value="">Not avaialble </option>' );
        echo json_encode($temp);
    }
}
```

But I'm not getting output result from it, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: use console.log(data) to see the return output and also parse json before  using return data object.

Comment: try to output `course` via `console.log` after you assigned the result of `$('#course').val()`. If it's not defined, you will get no response.

Comment: @TobiasF. I have outputed the course as well as the department value , they are working fine.

Comment: I think you should try @scaisEdge s answer, it seems he is right.

Comment: In case you're not already aware, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterised queries instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax call expects JSON (`dataType: 'json'`) but you do not return JSON via your PHP output because the default content type is `text/html` and not `application/json`. Add the appropriate `Content-Type` header before `echo`'ing your JSON output.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('something' => 'else'));
```

Comment: Actually I have used json before this too , and they were working fine with single post variable.

Answer (score 0):

you echo an array  so you should  access  to data element  as an array by index ..

eg for first element

```
       success: function(data){
            $('#head_name').html(data[0].head_name);
            $('#email').html(data[0].email);
        }
```

eventually  try jsonParse data

```
       success: function(data){
             jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#head_name').jsonData(data[0].head_name);
            $('#email').jsonData(data[0].email);
        }
```

in your while  you should   use an array for store the values

```
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

        $temp[] = array('head_name' => '<option value="'.$row['head_name'].'">'.$row['head_name'].'</option>', 'email' => '<option value="'.$row['email'].'">'.$row['email'].'</option>' );
        echo json_encode($temp);
    }
```

Comment: still not working, and one more thing it is working If I'm sending only one variable in data

Comment: i have asked  for see the result  .of . var_dump( json_encode($temp));  .. if you let me see the result . i can  eval it , otherwise  ..  i can't tell you nothing

Comment: var_dump( json_encode($temp)); does output anything

Comment: hey buddy looks like I just need to rename the variable value of course and the function is working

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge , I'm getting one more problem in this, actually this function was working good if there is single record in database but if there is more than one it does not showing values , may be I don't know how to populate the json array , can u please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just change the variable name of course and my function starts working , don't know why like this:

```
data:{ department: department, courseid: course},
```

Comment: Is it giving you the expected results from your query, or just "not avaialble"?